# How do I make a button appear after inputting text in an HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm coding an HTML form where I've implemented an anti-spam system where two random numbers are generated and the user is asked to input the sum into a text field. If the answer is right, then the 'submit' button appears and the user can move on. If the answer is incorrect, then a notification saying, 'Incorrect answer'. The HTML form itself is in a table. In the very last row of cells I've put this code in:

```
<td>
<?php 
$firstnumber = rand(0, 5);
$secondnumber = rand(0,6);
echo 'Anti-spam: '.$firstnumber.' + '.$secondnumber.' = ?</td><td><input name="human" placeholder = "Do the math">'; 
?>
</td>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
By submitting this form you are agreeing to the <a href="http://http://j2partners.net/index.php?site=tos" target="_blank">terms of service and agreements.</a><br><br>
<?php 
$answer = $_POST['human'];
if($answer == $firstnumber + $secondnumber) {
echo '<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="I Agree"> <input id="reset" name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset">'; } 
else {
echo '<font color=#ea596c>Incorrect answer</font>';
?>
</td>
```

But the 'submit' button won't reappear when the answer is entered into the box :(

Comment: Firstly echo out `$answer` and sum `$firstnumber + $secondnumber`. Check if both match or not and try this `($answer == ($firstnumber + $secondnumber))`

Comment: You need to `POST` a form with the value before `$_POST` is populated. Otherwise you will need `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add some JavaScript to your form to achieve that.
Add a keypress event on input and check if entry is valid.

```
<input id="antispam" name="human" onkeyup="checkEntry" placeholder = "Do the math">'; 
?>

<script>
function checkEntry()
{
var x=document.getElementById("antispam");
if (x=={correct answare})
  {
    [add submite button]
  }
else
{
   [add incorrect text]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**option 1** (not too secure) add hidden input with correct answer

```
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?=$firstnumber+$secondnumber;?"/>
```

and check the data after submit

```
if($_POST["anwer"]==$_POST["human"]) ...
```

**option 2** remember the correct answer with SESSION. If you want to do **server side check**, you must display submit button - the data must be sent to the server. To display/hide the submit button, you must do **client side check** and use javascript, see option 3.

```
<?
  session_start(); // necessary to use session vars
  $firstnumber = rand(0, 5);
  $secondnumber = rand(0, 6);
  if(!empty($_SESSION["answer"]) && $_SESSION["answer"]==@$_POST["human"]) {
    // the math was ok
  }
  $_SESSION["answer"] = $firstnumber + $secondnumber; // must be AFTER the check
?>
<form method="post">
  <?="$firstnumber + $secondnumber = ";?>
  <input name="human" type="text" placeholder="do the math"/>
  <input type="submit"/> <!-- can't be hidden without javascript -->
</form>
```

**option 3** client side javascript solution, something like vasiljevski recommend

```
<span id="first"></span> + <span id="first"></span>
<input oninput="check(this)" placeholder="do the math"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit" style="display: none"/>

<script>
  var first=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var second=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var gid = document.getElementById.bind(document);
  gid("first").innerHTML = first;
  gid("second").innerHTML = second;
  function check(input) {
    gid("submit").style.display = input.value==first+second ? "inline" : "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I used option 2. $_SESSION["answer"] is working fine but it still won't recognize what the user inputted answer is :(

Answer (score 1):

You are generating new random numbers on every page load. So when the user is doing the math and submitting the form, it happens a new request and your random numbers are generated new, so the calculation cannot match (randomly it could be the same result).

You have to store the math result in session or an hidden input field (encoded or something else) that you know the result after submitting the form.

Or you want to check the result in JavaScript to show the button, but I wouldn't do an humanity check on the client.